# Reverse URL in Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-2.0

The new Django 2.0 update broke my way of reversing url and printing it to the template. Using regular expression, it would work fine but when using the new simplified way, it returns an error.

```
NoReverseMatch at /blog/archive/
Reverse for 'article' with keyword arguments '{'id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/article/<int:id>/$']
```

Here is what I use to print the url,

```
<h3 class="item-title"><a href="{% url 'blog:article' id=article.id %}">{{ article.title }}</a></h3>
```

Here is the url pattern,

```
    url(r'^blog/article/<int:id>/$', views.article, name='article'),
```

and here is the article function,

```
def article(request, id):
    try:
        article = Article.objects.get(id=id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        article = None

    context = {
        'article': article,
        'error': None,
    }

    if not article:
        context['error'] = 'Oops! It seems that the article you requested does not exist!'

    return render(request, 'blog/article.html', context)
```

I haven't found a solution to this yet. Hopefully this post will help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Django 2.0, [`url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#url) is an alias for [`re_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#re-path) and still uses regular expressions.

Use [`path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path) for the simplified syntax.

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^blog/article/<int:id>/$', views.article, name='article'),
]
```

Comment: Thank you dear stanger, I should have read more about the update. Seems like they changed a lot of things. My site works now!